# How to get the month duration in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a `startdate` and and `enddate`in the format `Y-m-d`.

```
'startdate'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Input::get('startdate'))),
'enddate'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Input::get('enddate')))
```

How can I get the Duration between these two days, like `2 months` or `1 month` or `2 weeks` in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) class, which is already included in Laravel 4, to get the difference between two days in a human-readable format.

```
$startDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', Input::get('startdate'));
$endDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', Input::get('enddate'));

echo $startDate->diffForHumans($endDate);
```

Comment: If you don't need the trailed word 'before'/'after':

`echo preg_replace('/(.*) (before|after)/', '$1', $startDate->diffForHumans($endDate));`

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it is `Carbon`

```
$start = new Carbon(date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Input::get('startdate'))));
$end = new Carbon(date('Y-m-d', strtotime(Input::get('enddate'))));
$diff_days = $start->diff($end)->days;
```

Well, there are more, please look up the documentation for details: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-difference